# java Scanner reads only first 2048 bytes

Tags: java, windows, macos, java.util.scanner

I'm using java.util.Scanner to read file contents from classpath with this code:

```
String path1 = getClass().getResource("/myfile.html").getFile();

System.out.println(new File(path1).length()); // 22244 (correct)

String file1 = new Scanner(new File(path1)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
System.out.println(file1.length()); // 2048 (first 2k only)
```

Code runs from idea with command (maven test)

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/java/maven-3.0.4 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/java/maven-3.0.4/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/usr/share/java/maven-3.0.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --fail-fast --strict-checksums test
```

It was running perfectly on my win7 machine. But after I moved to mac same tests fail.
I tried to google but didn't find much =(

Why Scanner with delimiter \Z read my whole file into a string on win7 but won't do it on mac?
I know there're more ways to read a file, but I like this one-liner and want to understand why it's not working.
Thanks.

Comment: Aside from anything else, you're not comparing like with like in the test - `File.length()` gives a length in *bytes*, whereas `String.length()` gives a length in *characters*. It doesn't explain the difference here, but it's still an odd comparison to make. What's in the file?

Comment: isn't mac case sensitive? did you try to use low case `\\z`?

Comment: @fmodos interesting `\\z` gives first 1024 bytes, where `\\Z` 2048

Comment: @fmodos: Those mean different things in regular expressions. It's not a filename - and other than for filenames, I don't know what kind of case sensitivity difference you're talking about between Mac and Windows.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's HTML file and 22244 is its correct size in bytes yes

Comment: And does the Scanner's first token end at anything interesting, such as a line boundary or an embedded U+0000 character, on the Mac?

Comment: @JonSkeet that is true, I got confused here.

Comment: Resources are not files, and using the `File` class on them isn't going to work in general.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some info from java about it

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

> \Z    The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any
>
> \z    The end of the input

[Line terminators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt)

> A line terminator is a one- or two-character sequence that marks the
> end of a line of the input character sequence. The following are
> recognized as line terminators:
>
> A newline (line feed) character ('\n'), A carriage-return character
> followed immediately by a newline character ("\r\n"), A standalone
> carriage-return character ('\r'), A next-line character ('\u0085'), A
> line-separator character ('\u2028'), or A paragraph-separator
> character ('\u2029).

So use `\z` instead of `\Z`

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article about this method of entirely reading file with `Scanner`:

http://closingbraces.net/2011/12/17/scanner-with-z-regex/

In brief:

> Because a single read with “/z” as the delimiter should read
>   everything until “end of input”, it’s tempting to just do a single
>   read and leave it at that, as the examples listed above all do.
>
> In most cases that’s OK, but I’ve found at least one situation where
>   reading to “end of input” doesn’t read the entire input – when the
>   input is a SequenceInputStream, each of the constituent InputStreams
>   appears to give a separate “end of input” of its own. As a result, if
>   you do a single read with a delimiter of “/z” it returns the content
>   of the first of the SequenceInputStream’s constituent streams, but
>   doesn’t read into the rest of the constituent streams.

Beware of using it. It will be better to read it line-by-line, or use `hasNext()` checking until it will be real `false`.

**UPD:** In other words, try this code:

```
StringBuilder file1 = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path1)).useDelimiter("\\Z");

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
   file1.append(scanner.next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but that's not my case.
After I do 

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path1)).useDelimiter("\\Z");
    scanner.next();

scanner.hasNext() returns false, however the file hasn't been fully read yet

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this as well when using `nextLine()` on Mac, Java 7 update 45. Worse, after the line that is longer than 2048 bytes, the rest of the file is ignored and the Scanner thinks that it is already the end of file.

I change it to explicitly tell Scanner to use larger buffer, and it works.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(nf), 20*1024*1024), "utf-8");
```