# Scanner stops reading long input file

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, eof

I tried to read an entire file from standard input using Scanner, but it keeps stopping after a fairly short amount of input. My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestEOF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter("\\z");
        String whole = sc.next();
        System.out.println(whole);
    }
}
```

Supposedly this should make the scanner read all the way to the end of the file, but I find it keeps stopping after some 1000 characters or so. I have tried this with a bunch of different input text files and get a similar result each time, even when the input file has no unusual characters. I am running this by the command

```
java TestEOF < input.txt
```

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312563/java-scanner-reads-only-first-2048-bytes

Comment: What's in the file around the "stop position"?

Comment: It seems to be random as far as I can tell. It's stopped in the middle of a number, between text, between a pipe and a minus sign... Is the buffer likely to be a problem? What exactly does it mean anyhow? Does it store the whole thing in a statically-sized buffer before it returns the value?

Comment: I personally wouldn't use `Scanner` for this in the first place. Either just use a `Reader`, or use a library which has a "read whole file" method to do it for you - Guava does, for example.